# Drainage Effects on Series of Batteries with some Reversed

Tags: batteries

- Lets say you have three batteries.
- Each are 1.5V, put in series with the others, but one is reversed. ---[- +][- +][+ -]---
- The total voltage is 1.5V

How does the orientation of those batteries affect the drainage of them? Does this drop the volts, but increase the total mAh? Would they all theoretically drain at the same rate?

Comment: You might want to specify the charge state of the batteries and whether they are primary or secondary batteries (rechargable).  The reversed battery will tend to charge as the other two discharge.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of what would happen with a rechargeable battery there. I was thinking about primary batteries. Would this kind of thing then destroy the reversed primary battery?

Comment: I don't know exactly what distinguishes the chemistry of primary and secondary batteries, but often there are warning labels on primary batteries.  I'm guessing that the reverse process doesn't work well and gasses can be produced that might cause the casing to leak or explode.